# RSpec Autotest loops with failures, doesn't work when exceptions are added

Tags: ruby, rspec, autotest

I've been playing around with autotest trying to make it work all day.. but am having some problems...

I've been following https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki/autotest, I'm running with:

- Ruby 1.9.3-p194
- rspec 2.10.0
- ZenTest 4.8.1

I also created a .rspec file.

So with this setup, I run autotest, and it works - my test runs, it passes, hooray!. When I stick a failure into my test e.g. false.should == true, then the test starts looping, over and over again.

what happens is that it's an integration test, and I'm writing to an sqlite db. If I run `find . -mmin -1` then I'm able to see that my db folder has changed - so I figured this is the problem.

So I edit .autotest and add the following:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  %w{db}.each { |exception| autotest.add_exception(exception) }
  false
end
```

But now when I run autotest, it just says the following:

```
loading autotest/rspec2
```

and that's it, it won't do anything anymore. Previously the output was:

`loading autotest/rspec2`

`/home/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S`   ``` '/home/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/exe/rspec' ``--tty '/home/me/Workspace/myproject/spec/integration/db/lead_spec.rb' ```

and then it'd run my test and show the result...

Anyone know what could be going on? it's very frustrating, and I feel like I've come to a road block....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe %w{db} is matching your spec name? Trying making it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autotest checks if defined exceptions match any part of the filename. Your spec has `db` in it's path so it is ignored by autotest.

If you want to ignore `db` folder, then do the following:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |a|
  a.add_exception %r{^\./db}
end
```